# VB restart form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a button and I need it to restart the form
I have no idea how to work on the visual basic what should i write

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say restart form what exactly do you mean?

Comment: as in C# restart(); I want to reload the form with clean fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean `Application.Restart()` ?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

  Application.Restart()

End Sub
```

Although in Visual Basic this does the same as in C#, it restarts the *application* not just clears the form.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reload the form you simply need to do this in the form's Load event.

```
Me.Close()
Me.Show()
```

Comment: That just seems like it will create a useless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Restart()
End Sub
```